# Flutter textfield format currency lag/delay

Tags: flutter, dart

is there a some way to do a money format in textfield flutter ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixbMr.png)

I use [this package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_masked_text)

and also use this code

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
class CurrencyPtBrFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  CurrencyPtBrFormatter({this.maxDigits});
  final int maxDigits;
  double umaskValue;
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
      return newValue;
    }
    if (maxDigits != null && newValue.selection.baseOffset > maxDigits) {
      return oldValue;
    }
    double value = double.parse(newValue.text);
    final formatter = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "pt_BR");
    String newText = "R\$ " + formatter.format(value / 100);
    //setting the umasked value
    umaskValue = value / 100;
    return newValue.copyWith(
        text: newText,
        selection: new TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newText.length));
  }
  //here the method
  double getUnmaskedText() {
    return umaskValue;
  }
}
```

its working fine, but  I got delay/lag when typing multiple lines

is there any solution ?

Comment: have you got the answer?

Comment: just use this package https://pub.dev/packages/currency_input_formatters, its works fine for me,